# Playframework [Acpache Deployment Issue]: Application is not reacheble when using public ip

Tags: apache, deployment, playframework, httpd.conf

I am trying to deploy my application on a Centos 7 server. I can get to my application when I type the local LAN address in my browser, but if I try to use my public ip address; I get a 504 error (I try this from outside my local network or I would get on my router page).

I configured my `httpd.conf` file as they say in the guide

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
 <VirtualHost *:80>
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ServerName mypublicip
  ProxyPass  /excluded !
  ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:9000/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:9000/
</VirtualHost>
```

and I forwarded the port on my router, so that the TCP/UDP traffic that get on `my.public.ip:80` is forwarded to `my.local.ip:80`.

However I can't access it.

Answer (score 0):

There should be firewall or some network issue. If it is working fine locally , then it should work from remote server. Because after going through your conf file, I do not see any reason for it not to be accessible.

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration looks fine, so what is left is the reachability:

1. Are you using [hosts filter](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/AllowedHostsFilter)?; what domains you are allowing to access your application instance?
2. If you are using a cloud service (e.g., aws), are you allowing everyone to access your ip through HTTP?

**Little advice here**: Definitely use HTTPS on your front HTTP server/ load balancer, that redirects to your Play instance.